# How to interpret ACF/PACF plots with no recent lag correlations?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, autocorrelation, trend, acf-pacf

I have a time-series data that looks like this:

[image]

There is obviously an upward trend in this data, so I do differencing with lag of 1, i.e.,
Series = Y(t) - Y(t-1)

The differenced series looks as follows:

[image]

When I compute and plot the ACF and PACF for the obtained time series above, I get the following plots:

[image]
[image]

In the PACF, no recent lags show significant correlation, however, at lag 9 there is a very high correlation - what does this mean? **Can somebody please help me understand how to interpret these plots and what conclusion should I arrive to about the p, d, q parameters of an ARIMA model for this data?**

Thanks in advance. I'm a novice.

EDIT: Below are the ACF/PACF plots for the original time-series:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you show the ACF/PACF plots of the original time series?

Comment: @user2974951 Added as EDIT...

Comment: Does a cycle of 13/14 units mean anything to you?

Comment: Also, why is your partial correlation >1?

Comment: Your first mistake is to take the first difference of a series that does not have a unit root. There are other ways to handle trends, e.g. fit a deterministic function of time to the data and extract the fitted values as your trend.